# how to change a part of urls using javascript

Tags: javascript

hi i went to change a part of urls please help me
**here's my code**

```
<script>
<!-- javascript -->
</script>

<div class="image">
<img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-UKS5LdO25Gw/VuBJoOR50FI/AAAAAAAARHs/006EudMG_gk/s72-c/j1mini.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image">
<img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-411tLg200L0/VuAH-4z3zqI/AAAAAAAAdYY/0GFl4x7K9bk/s72-c/etoro.jpeg">
</div>
<div class="image">
<img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-wv3KvVVLZwI/VtyYmB6LRUI/AAAAAAAAHV0/a86DOrdL1js/s72-c/Untitled-1.png">
</div>
```

i went to change the **s72** to **s300**

**note :** there is many urls

Answer (score 1):

```
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var image = images[i];
    image.src = image.src.replace('s72', 's300');
  }
```

This is dangerous to do replacement like this. If "s72" occurs elsewhere in the image url other than where you're trying to replace it, things will go bad.

Comment: the 2.bp.blogspot.com it changin like 3.b.blogspot.com ... 1.bp.blospot.com ect....

Comment: i went to change only only the: **s72**

Comment: @abdeldiwat This solution is work for your question!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an IDE or text editor like Sublime, then you can use the Find->Replace->Replace All functionality to change all the s72s to s300s.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
function changeSizeImages() {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll(".image img");
  var total = images.length;
  for(var i = 0; i<total; i++) {
    images[i].src = images[i].src.replace("s72", "s300");
  }
}
```